# Behavior in case of pointer increment. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int* p = new int(3);
    p+=4;
    std::cout<<*p<<std::endl;
}
```

My compiler (Visual Studio 2012) prints: `-7514522142` int this case.
So can we somehow deduce the output and is this code legal?

Comment: You're going out of bounds of the *single* integer you have allocated. Dereferencing memory you don't own leads to *undefined behavior* which renders your whole program ill-formed.

Comment: No, and No..... Given that `new` code, it wouldn't be legal even with `p+=1;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are accessing memory (allocated for a single `int` object) out of bounds. The behaviour is *undefined*, i.e. not deducible. The program should not be considered legal, despite being syntactically valid.

Answer (score 4):

> So can we somehow deduce the output and is this code legal?

Pointers are incremented in multiples of the size of the type they point to. When you add 4 to `p`, you're adding `4 * sizeof(int)`, not just 4 bytes.

If you're trying to make `p` point to the "next" integer, increment it by 1, not 4. Otherwise, `p` will point to memory beyond the end of what you allocated.

In fact, if I'm not mistaken your allocation only creates a single `int` with the value 3, not three separate `int`s:

```
int* p = new int(3);
```

Try commenting out the `p += 4;` line and you should get '3' as the output. Considering that, juanchopanza's answer above is spot on.